# Flutter sending data to other pages in stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How to send data to other screen help me out.
am using data table api but it need the json in string array so i want to send data to the data table page. how to send data after reading the json file. Help me out.

Comment: the code you already produced would have been nice though. This its far easier to answer.

Comment: its so big but so far your code satisfy my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not provided any code, its hard to know exactly what you are trying. But passing data down to child looks like this (when you dont want to use state management libs like Provider or BLOC).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // read json....
    var myObjReadFromJSON = null; //your implementation here
    return Child(myObjReadFromJSON);
  }
}

class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  var myObjReadFromJSON;


  Child(this.myObjReadFromJSON);

  @override
  _ChildState createState() => _ChildState(myObjReadFromJSON);
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {
  var myObjReadFromJSON;


  _ChildState(this.myObjReadFromJSON);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // do something with myObjReadFromJSON here.....
    return ListView(

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great sir ..... help me alot

Comment: great it was of help for you. Take care.